# Perl Extended Regular Expressions - match with multiple question marks inside

Tags: regex, perl

I have got a weird thing to solve in perl using regular expressions.

Consider the strings -

```
abcdef000000123

blaDeF002500456

wefdEF120045423
```

All of these strings are matching with the below regular expression when I tried in C with pcre library support :

```
???[dD][eE][fF][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

But I'm unable to achieve the same in perl code. I'm getting some weird errors.

Please help with the piece of perl code with which these two things match.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you show us some code?

Comment: Hi devnull,
Thanks for the response.
Replacing ? with . is working fine for me (as per the expectation of the mentioned regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` is called quantifier that makes preceding pattern or group an optional match.  **Independently `?` doesn't make any sense** in regex and you are getting an error like: `Quantifier follows nothing in regex`.

Following regex should work for you in perl:

```
...[dD][eE][fF][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

OR even more concise regex:

```
.{3}[dD][eE][fF][0-9]{9}
```

Each dot means match any character.

**PS:** You probably are getting confused by shell's glob vs regex.

Comment: Hi anubhava,

Thanks for the help.
Replacing the ? with . is working as expected. But curious to know how the pcre library treating them. will check it.

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget marking accepted mark if you're satisfied with the answer. As I wrote PCRE won't accept `?` independently.

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like a file system regex than a PCRE.  In Perl, the `?` is a quantifier, not a wild card.  You may want to replace them with `.` to get the same results in anything Perl compatible.

I might use `...[dD][eE][fF][0-9]{9}` or even replace the `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

`qr/[A-z]{3}def[0-9]{9}/i`

should be the `Perl Regex` object used to validate the mentioned strings.

Regards